# Google Sheet conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to get a format: I want the cel in column A be orange when the date is past and the task is nog checkt done. This is working, but he formats my hole range. A second formatting with a Cel is blank doesn't work. If there is no task i don't want it to be orange..

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem comes from the `$` in your formula

It formats all cells based on row 4.

Additionally, if you want to implement the condition that the date should not be blank, you need to add into your `AND` statement `ISBLANK(D4)=FALSE`

Change your formula to

`=AND(D4<TODAY(),E4=FALSE,ISBLANK(D4)=FALSE)`

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka,

Thank you for you comment, but i still have the same problem. whole column A is orange except A4

Comment: I see, you do not want to apply the formatting to rows where the data is empty? I will update my response.

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean.